# cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<_, _>' to type 'Dictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to grab a set of menu items.  I'm fairly new to swift and programming in general, and therefore don't always know how to structure my data properly.  Since each menu item has a name, price, and description, I'm storing it as a dictionary, and trying to store all of the items together in an array of "Menu Item" dictionaries.

```
var menuItem : Dictionary = ["itemID" : String(), "itemName" : String(), "itemDescription" : String(), "itemPrice" : String()]
var menu = [[String: String]]()

func getMenuItems(){
    let itemsRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/menu")
    itemsRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {

            var newItem = self.menuItem

            newItem["itemID"] = id.key as String
            newItem["itemName"] = id.value["itemName"] as? String
            newItem["itemDescription"] = id.value["itemDescription"] as? String
            newItem["itemPrice"] = id.value["itemPrice"] as? String
            self.menu.append(newItem)
        }

    })//End get menu info
}
```

When I try and run this code, I get this error:

```
(!) cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<_, _>' to type 'Dictionary'
```

Am I declaring my dictionary wrong?  Am I just adding unnecessary complexity by trying to store dictionaries in an array?

Comment: Which line giving you the error?

Comment: It's not showing on a specific line, just showing up at the bottom of the Issue Navigator.

Comment: Just try this: `var newItem = [String:String]()` instead of `var newItem = self.menuItem`

Comment: Although dictionary is one of the solutions, but by looking at your code it is better to use a custom object (Class) for your menuItem, so that your code can be simpler and have subclasses

Comment: Awesome @PeterLee, thanks.  I think you're right, that'll make the whole thing easier to work with.